# Metamind Ajax request not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest, post

I am a newbie to the Ajax request. I want to post to Metamind API but it returns to me the 405 error. Here is the Curl description used in the tutorial: http://docs.metamind.io/docs/image-classification, and here is my Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://www.metamind.io/vision/classify",
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){    
             xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Authorization:","Basic <My_Authorization_Key>");},
        dataType:"jsonp",
        data: '{"classifier_id":"food-net",
                "image_url":"https://www.metamind.io/static/images/classification-demo-examples/macarons.jpg"}'
    })
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "https://www.metamind.io/vision/classify",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic yourkey");
                },
                data: '{"classifier_id":"food-net", "image_url":"https://www.metamind.io/static/images/classification-demo-examples/macarons.jpg"}',
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                    console.log(msg);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    console.log("FAIL");
                    console.log(msg.responseText);
                }
            });
```

And for those who prefer AngularJS $http:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic yourkey';
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                //data: '{"classifier_id":"food-net", "image_url":"http://www.ndtv.com/cooks/images/pizza-junk-food-600.jpg"}',
                data: '{"classifier_id":"food-net", "image_url": "' + base64Img + '"}',
                url: "https://www.metamind.io/vision/classify"
            }).success(function (result) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                console.log(result);
            }).error(function (err) {
                console.log("FAIL");
                console.log(err);
            });
```